# input :Specified cast is not valid

Tags: api, rest, xamarin, xamarin.forms, service

I tried to execute my application Rest api. Using a breakpoint, I found a problm in this line:

`expenses.AmountTTC = Convert.ToDecimal(ttc.Text);`
The error is "Specified cast is not valid".
AmountTTC has the type decimal? in the model , same for my service(i have two projects, one for the services and anthor for my mobile application).

```
 private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ajoutD.Clicked += async delegate
        {
            try
            {
                LoginViews expenses = new LoginViews();
               expenses.Name = nameLib.Text;
                expenses.StartDate = dataDe.Date;
                expenses.EndDate = dateAu.Date;
                datenow.Date = DateTime.Now;
                expenses.Description = description.Text;
                expenses.CurrencyId = Convert.ToInt32(devises.Id);

                expenses.AmountTTC = Convert.ToDecimal(ttc.Text);
                remb.Text = expenses.AmountReimbursed.ToString();
                expenses.Remboursable = Convert.ToBoolean(isremboursable);
                expenses.Provider = marchand.Text;
                HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();

               HttpResponseMessage response;
                var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(expenses);
                var content = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, content);
                AuthResponse responseData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<AuthResponse>(response?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync()?.Result);
                if (responseData.data.Success)
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("heey", "connexion done", "ok");
                                      }
                else
                {
                    await DisplayAlert("wake up !", responseData.data.ErrorMessage, "attention");
                }
            }catch(Exception eee)
            {
                string msg = eee.ToString();
            }
        };

    }
```

Comment: Try    expenses.AmountTTC = Convert.ToDouble(ttc.Text);

Comment: without knowing the value ttc.Text there's noway could determine why the exception is happening, I will assume that it's numeric value, in this case please make sure that they contain no spaces by using .Replace(" ", string.Empty) and make sure the decimal format passed is consistent with your current culture

Comment: I already tried to extract the value of the field in a new variable and convert it, and it is done. but i dont know what is the problem @Scarnet

Comment: @Anand I cannot convert to double because the type in the model is in decimal, and even when I tried to convert to double, an error appears: impossible to convert decimal?  in double

Comment: Can you please share us an example of the value  ttc.Text then we can test it on our side?  BTW, you can share your solution in the answer so that it will help more people with same problem.